Passing a Layout To an other Layout in blazor
I have a layout that contains a Gridview which has a typeparam as an input. The type param is a Class. So the gridview Loads the properties of the Class. So how can I have an other input that accepts a razor page(contains an edit form) to show in the layout as when as needed?


First pic is the layout.
Second page is the component that I want to have them as a input for the first pic.
I have a lot of this razor pages that I need to call them in the first picture.

Show some code.  "a layout that contains a Gridview" does sound right.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis check it now .
